# Laptop Sony is constantly hot. How to fix it?

Tags: vaio, overheating

I have Sony Vaio pcG-392M. The video is "GeForce 8400M GT". I use XBMC on it most of the time. Ubuntu 12.04. Kernel 3.2.0-33-generic-pae.

**The problem:**

Fan is on most of the time. CPU stays 70C, gets that hot minutes after the PC is turned on, the temp never goes down, even if the machine is idling.

I updated Nvidia drivers, installed sensors and `powertop`, but cannot figure out what is causing the instant load. Here is the output of both:

sensors:
(The machine was playing music for 20 minutes before getting the output, it is usually 70 after reboot)

```
acpitz-virtual-0 Adapter: Virtual device  

temp1: +94.0°C (crit =+127.0°C) 
temp2: +94.0°C (crit = +105.0°C) 
coretemp-isa-0000 Adapter: ISA adapter Core 0: +92.0°C (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1: +92.0°C (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

`powertop` - Overview:

```
Usage Events/s Category Description
100.0% Device Audio codec hwC0D0: SigmaTel 
1.9 ms/s 87.1 Interrupt [6] tasklet(softirq) 
60.2 µs/s 27.4 kWork ieee80211_iface_work 
160.9 µs/s 15.7 Timer tick_sched_timer 
258.7 µs/s 9.8 Interrupt [23] ehci_hcd:usb2 
168.6 µs/s 9.8 Process syndaemon -i 2.0 -K -R -t 
67.1 µs/s 8.8 Timer hrtimer_wakeup 
43.4 µs/s 8.8 Process [RTKTHREAD] 
12.9 ms/s 2.9 Process powertop 
361.2 µs/s 4.9 Process /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background no 
0.0 µs/s 3.9 kWork BlinkWorkItemCallback 
2.0 ms/s 2.0 Process unity-2d-shell 
140.0 µs/s 2.0 Process /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon 
370.0 µs/s 1.0 Process NetworkManager 
318.4 µs/s 1.0 Process dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart 
149.5 µs/s 1.0 Process /usr/lib/ubuntu-geoip/ubuntu-geoip-provider 
137.9 µs/s 1.0 Process /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5 
123.2 µs/s 1.0 Process sshd: deckoff@pts/0 
81.2 µs/s 1.0 Process /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon 
74.6 µs/s 1.0 Process /usr/lib/unity-lens-applications/unity-applications-daemon 
66.1 µs/s 1.0 Process /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.9 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0 
61.0 µs/s 1.0 Process zeitgeist-datahub 
58.2 µs/s 1.0 Process nautilus -n 
30.2 µs/s 1.0 Process /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor 
12.5 µs/s 1.0 kWork flush_to_ldisc 
12.1 µs/s 1.0 Timer watchdog_timer_fn 
4.9 µs/s 1.0 Process [watchdog/1] 
4.5 µs/s 1.0 Process [watchdog/0] 
1.5 ms/s 0.0 Interrupt [16] nvidia 
0.9 ms/s 0.0 Interrupt [47] iwl3945 
382.9 µs/s 0.0 Process [migration/1]
269.4 µs/s 0.0 Interrupt [16] yenta 
263.9 µs/s 0.0 Process nm-applet 
249.1 µs/s 0.0 Interrupt [0] timer/0
```

Idle stats:

```
Package | CPU 0 POLL 0.0% | POLL 0.0% 0.0 ms C1 0.0% | C1 0.0% 0.0 ms  C2 0.0% | C2 0.0% 0.0 ms C3 99.3% | C3 99.2% 6.7 ms
| CPU 1 | POLL 0.0% 0.0 ms | C1 0.0% 0.0 ms | C2 0.0% 0.3 ms | C3 99.5% 6.6 ms
```

Frequency stats:

```
Package | CPU 0 Turbo Mode 0.3% | Turbo Mode 0.3% 
2.00 Ghz 0.0% | 2.00 Ghz 0.0% 
1.60 Ghz 0.0% | 1.60 Ghz 0.0% 1200 Mhz 0.0% | 1200 Mhz 0.0% 800 Mhz 0.0% 
| 800 Mhz 0.0% Idle 99.7% | Idle 99.7% 
| CPU 1 | Turbo Mode 0.0% | 2.00 Ghz 0.0% | 1.60 Ghz 0.0% | 1200 Mhz 
 0.0% | 800 Mhz 0.0% | Idle 100.0%
```

Device Stats

```
Usage Device name

0.9% CPU use
100.0% Audio codec hwC0D0: SigmaTel 
513.4 pkts/s Network interface: wlan0 (iwl3945)
132.3 pkts/s Network interface: wlan1 (rtl8192cu)
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 5
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection 
100.0% PCI Device: Texas Instruments 5-in-1 Multimedia Card Reader (SD/MMC/MS/MS PRO/xD) 
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller 
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 3
100.0% Radio device: iwl3945 
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
100.0% PCI Device: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller 
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] 
100.0% PCI Device: NVIDIA Corporation G86 [GeForce 8400M GT] 
100.0% USB device: UHCI Host Controller 
100.0% USB device: UHCI Host Controller 
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 
100.0% USB Device: usb-device-05ca-183b 
100.0% USB device: 802.11n WLAN Adapter (Realtek) 
100.0% USB device: EHCI Host Controller 
100.0% USB device: EHCI Host Controller 
100.0% USB device: UHCI Host Controller 
100.0% USB device: UHCI Host Controller 
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 PCI Express Root Port 
100.0% PCI Device: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8036 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller 
100.0% USB device: UHCI Host Controller 
100.0% PCI Device: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller 
100.0% PCI Device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Your using the Proprietary Graphics Drivers? Have you checked the Power Management settings? They are available in the 'nvidia-settings' utility, under the 'PowerMizer' tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with my vaio laptop, but I have a radeon HD graphic card which are worst than Nvidia usually. After weeks of search here is my last solution :

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Open the `/etc/rc.local` file entering this command: `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`
3. Put the following command into the file, *before the `exit 0` line*

   `sudo bash -c "echo low > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_profile"`
4. Save and close the file and reboot the computer.

[An example of how your file should look like](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1398142/).

This command will put the energy profile in `low` mode, so it will decrease the consuming, this should increase the battery life too.

NOTE: I use the open source drive, it's the best but I think for Nvidia you should go for the proprietary.

Comment: What exactly does this do. It seems this is used mainly for Nvidia cards

Comment: Hi. I have Vaio VPCS11M9R. I tried to follow your advice, but didn't find /sys/class/drm.... sub-directory in my case. I have NVIDIA GT218M and my fans are constantly working, though in case of windows 7 I got managed to decrease them... Maybe you have some mor e advices?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately nvidia graphics tend to get mighty hot (trust me, I have experienced this) and in most systems with a good processor + nvidia graphics + a non-ssd drive, 70C is actually a good temperature (unless maybe you are in an air-conditioned environment).

If you know how, you can use compressed air to clean the vents, but it will only be a temporary solution, and should get your system's idle temperature to the 40s or so. I'm sorry there isn't much of a better solution.

Comment: Cleaning did not help, unfortunately:(

Comment: Is there a way to decrease the fan speed for Nvidia? I got managed to make that on windows7, but not possible to do that with Ubuntu13.04 :(